# How to use $$ in mathjax to be inline?

Tags: mathjax, cancel

I have used the following code to display inline mathjax

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
MathJax.Hub.Config({tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']]}});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" async
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.4/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML">
</script>
```

When I use this

```
$\sqrt{\frac{(6²)(\require{cancel}\cancel5)}{5\times5\times\cancel5}}$
```

Then it shows this rendered expression
[image]

And it is on the left side means it is not in the mid of the page.

But you can see that I want to cancel 5 and it is not properly strike.

But when I use

```
$$\sqrt{\frac{(6²)(\require{cancel}\cancel5)}{5\times5\times\cancel5}}$$
```

Then it shows this rendered expression [image]

You can see it properly strikes but out of the line and comes in mid.

Now, I want the number to properly strike and on the left side just below other expressions.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Be aware that *MathJax* only uses LaTeX syntax but is not LaTeX (as fas as I understand) (see http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html, e. g. "While MathJax includes nearly all of the Plain TeX math macros, and many of the LaTeX macros and environments, not everything is implemented in the core TeX input processor.").

Comment: By the way, your last question (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/461665) is considered off-topic since it is about MathJax and not about LaTeX. Maybe this is the wrong forum for you (I am not an expert on the policy here).

Answer (score 2):

I tried using `math.stackexchange.com` and it shows a good result as follows. Yours might have some misconfiguration.

[image]

For further detailed investigation, please submit your question to `www.stackoverflow.com` with tag `mathjax`.

Comment: What misconfiguration? Everything and code just is mentioned before you. And how to post in math.stackexchange.com. When I try to post then it says I must have 5 points or something like that.

Comment: +1: @ShayaanMustafa Please calm down. I think that Artificial Stupidity tried your code on an input box (as asking a question but just to test your code) on math.stackexchange.com and had a look at the result.

Comment: @ShayaanMustafa: You must not submit this problem in `math.stackexchange.com` (because it is out of topic there) but you can use its editor to test your equations.

Comment: Thank you sir, I am not getting hyper. But just couple of hours ago I posted the question same and related to the mathjax in tex.stackexchange.com and one of the expert or moderator put my question on hold and said it is off topic and must be in math.stackexchange.com. I am wonder, moderators and experts don't know what to put where so how a newbie would? It is funny right? Well, is there any solution? I believe there must be any solution for this because nothing is impossible. Do I need to share my code further? Or anything else you guys want to analyze in my code? I am using blogspot.

Comment: @ShayaanMustafa: Please read the last edit in my answer.

Comment: OK. So, I have to submit it in stackoverflow.com? I will not get the answer here?